# Changing a variable outside a for loop from within the loop

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop

In this situation an array nums has an undefined amount of integers in it and I'm trying to find the largest and print it. When I do this a is always printed as 0 because whatever is happening in the loop doesn't affect the a value outside of it. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
int a = 0;
for(int i=0;i>nums.length;i++){
  if(nums[i]>a)
    a=nums[i];
  i++;}
System.out.print(a);
```

Comment: use i<nums.length

Comment: Was the double incrementation of `i` per iteration intended?

Comment: @PavneetSingh: IMHO, there's no harm in putting that as an answer, and dealing with the double `i++`.

Comment: When you step through this code in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: @Bathsheba and thanks , i appreciate it  :)

Answer (score 4):

This code has two errors:

1. the loop will never execute since `i` will start with a value less than `nums.length`
2. you increment the loop index twice!

Your loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
  if(nums[i]>a)
    a=nums[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();

    // Fill the ArrayList with integer RandomNumbers
    int size = r.nextInt(100);
    int maxValue = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
        int value = r.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println("Current value: " + value);
        arrayList.add(value);
        if(value > maxValue)
            maxValue = value;
    }

    System.out.println("Max: " + maxValue);
    // If u want to shuffle the list
    Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
  }
}
```